# Aggregate across two collections and update documents in first collect in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo. I have a collection for which I want to update fields based on values from another collection.
Here's a document from the collection1.

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5fef7a23d0bdc785d4fc94e7"),
  path: 'path1.png',
  type: 'negative',
  xmin: NaN,
  ymin: NaN,
  xmax: NaN,
  ymax: NaN}
```

And from collection2:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5fef7a24d0bdc785d4fc94e8"),
  path: 'path1.png',
  xmin: 200,
  ymin: 200,
  xmax: 300,
  ymax: 300}
```

How do I update collection 1 so that the example document looks like:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5fef7a23d0bdc785d4fc94e7"),
  path: 'path1.png',
  type: 'negative,
  xmin: 200,
  ymin: 200,
  xmax: 300,
  ymax: 300}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch collection2 into a `dict` variable and use `$set` to update collection1, e.g.

```
for doc in db.collection2.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
    db.collection1.update_one({'path': doc.get('path')}, {'$set': doc})
```

Comment: Sorry, I should I have clarified that I was looking for a solution to update more than one (all) documents in collection 1 in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to output it into a separate collection, but still not sure how to get it to the same collection.

```
db.collection1.aggregate[
    {
        '$match': {
            'xmin': 'NaN'
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'collection2', 
            'localField': 'path', 
            'foreignField': 'path', 
            'as': 'inferences'
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'inferences.xmin': 1, 
            'inferences.ymin': 1, 
            'inferences.xmax': 1, 
            'inferences.ymax': 1, 
            'path': 1,  
            'type': 1, 
            '_id': 0
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$inferences', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': False
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'xmin': '$inferences.xmin', 
            'ymin': '$inferences.ymin', 
            'xmax': '$inferences.xmax', 
            'ymax': '$inferences.ymax'
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'path': 1, 
            'type': 1, 
            'xmin': 1, 
            'ymin': 1, 
            'xmax': 1, 
            'ymax': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$out': 'collection3'
    }
]
```